# Bold every instance of a word in string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to bold every instance of a word in a string and also remove everything in the string before the first instance of the word.

I'm using `str_replace()` and `stristr()` to do this, but the output isn't as expected. Everything before the first instance of the word is cut off, but the instances of the word are not bold when I echo the string.

Here is my code:

```
$word="the";
$sentence = "Hello, did you hear the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$edited = stristr((str_replace($word, ("<span class=\"found\">".$word."</span>"), ($sentence))), $word);
echo $edited;
```

And the CSS for the class to make it bold:

```
.found{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

What I want is this:

> **the** quick brown fox jumped over **the** lazy dog

or

```
<span class="found">the</span> quick brown fox jumped over <span class="found">the</span> lazy dog
```

when echoed.

But what I get is this:

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

or

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

when echoed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$edited = stristr($sentence, $word);
$edited = str_ireplace($word, '<span class="found">'.$word.'</span>', $edited);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uFMafc).

---

Or better yet (preserves the original case and only bolds whole `$word`s):

```
$edited = stristr($sentence, $word);
$edited = preg_replace('~\b(' . preg_quote($word, '~') . ')\b~i', '<span class="found">$1</span>', $edited);
```

[Another demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nais4M).

Comment: I am try to use your logic of reversing the order of the functions, but for some reason this isn't working. Any ideas why? `$queryReplace = "<span class=\"found\">".$query."</span>"; $descriptionContent = $elasticaResult->content; $foundQuery = stristr($descriptionContent, $query); $queryInDescription = str_replace($query, $queryReplace, $foundQuery); echo $queryInDescription;`

Comment: @irfanmir: `var_dump($elasticaResult);`

Comment: What does that mean? You want me to var_dump() it in the code, why?

Comment: @irfanmir: I want you to post the var_dump of the object. Because, if the code works by itself (as you can see in the 3 demos), there is a good chance the problem lies in the content. You also say that "it isn't working" but you don't say why or post any additional information that might help us help you, hence the `var_dump`.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you for the help. Here is the var_dump: http://pastebin.com/XtydCjkw. What I am trying to get in this case ($query = 'google') is `<span class="found">Google</span> Glass Photographer by gogrovo 607,503 views | 4 days ago 1:30 Watch: A car that runs on your tweets and Facebook likes by ibnlive 301 views | 13 hours ago 2:14...`

Comment: @irfanmir: `$elasticaResult->content` is not set (unless you're using magic methods), should be something like `$elasticaResult->_hit["_source"]["content"]`. Does `var_dump($elasticaResult->content);` output the actual content?

Comment: @irfanmir: Additionally, it works here http://3v4l.org/Y7c24 - so I guess your original question has been answered correctly. I suggest you check the rest of your code for possible typos and if you can't still figure it out, ask a new question with all the necessary details.

Comment: Yes, `var_dump($elasticaResult->content);` does return the actual content.

Comment: The code you posted in the last link works! On my copy! Thank you!